# convert portion of byte array values to String

Tags: java

I have loaded the entire file into a byte[] array using following code:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Now i would like to get the first 120 characters as String and any string info from from index and to index.

Could you please let me know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a string constructor that takes a byte array.

Comment: What do you mean by "and any string info from from index and to index"?

Comment: Thanks Sam..Jon replied it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're just looking for [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-java.nio.charset.Charset-):

```
String text = new String(data, 0, 120, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(Always specify the encoding explicitly when converting between binary and text forms.)